# how to create the xml rpc server that handles xml rpc request in java?

Tags: java, xml-rpc, simplexmlrpcserver

In a java class,the Xml rpc webserver is listing to the client requests (by url like http://localhost:8056/) and the xml request is having multiple number of lines like

```
<methodCall>
<methodName>method1</methodName>
<params>
<param><value><string>hello1</string></value></param>
<param><value><string>hello2</string></value></param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

how to catch all the parameters which are going to vary by request to request.. but every we have to use the same method to process the request.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [Apache XML-RP](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/)C library which does all parsing for you?